# Paypal IPN difference normal to mobile devices

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Coovachilli and processing wifi payments via Paypal. When I go through the process with a laptop Paypal loads in a few seconds but when I use mobile(only tested on Android) devices it takes 2 minutes to get to a page with 2 buttons on it about paying via paypal account or credit card. I select paypal and it takes another 3 minutes to get to the page that my laptop reached in one step and a few seconds. I've tried different browsers on the Android tablet and phone but get the same result.

Because I have to allow Paypal through the captive portal for this to work I'm wondering if there is a different url that is required for mobiles devices that I need to allow through.

At the moment I'm allowing

- *.paypal.com
- *.paypalobjects.com

The POST I'm sending to Paypal is to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
and the variables are

- currency_code
- cmd value="_xclick
- business
- item_name
- item_number
- amount
- custom
- return
- notify_url
- cancel_return

It seems like it's waiting for a component to load and eventually times out and continues. Does anyone know what happens differently between laptops and mobile devices?

Comment: If I comment out the item_name the process drops the redirection to the mobile paypal and the payment page loads in a few seconds on mobile devices. So is there a way to disable being redirected to the mobile payment pages?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the pain of Coovachilli redirects...

I found success with `mobile.paypal.com` yet `.paypal.com or paypal.com` didnt always work.

I tested using a chrome url user agent changer and sniffer.

I also had an issue with the paypal headers and line breaks, not sure that was mobile related.